# Why does Nexus not provide correct POM file?

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a manually uploaded JAR file (with POM File) in the Nexus 3rd party repository. The 3rd party repository is part of the public repository group.

When downloading the POM from the public repository I receive only a minimal POM File (with groupId, artifactId and version, but missing the dependencies) whereas when downloading directly form 3rd party repo I get the correct complete POM.

I looked in the storage folder of the public repo group but there was no copy of the POM file.

Is there any magic in the Nexus repository groups that generates minimal POM files for some reason? I have no clue where the small POM files comes from. I updated/repaired the index of the repository group, but it did not help.

Comment: If you have uploaded have you checked off to generate the pom file during the upload ? Sounds like you didn't ...

Comment: The file was manually uploaded in the third party repository. When I download directly from that everything is fine: http://mynexus/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/mygroupid/myversion/myartifact.pom. Only when downloading from public repo group I get a wrong file: http://mynexus/nexus/content/repositories/public/mygroupid/myversion/myartifact.pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the very simple solution. The file was also uploaded (with wrong pom) to another repository which is part of the public repository group.